# Unable to run robomongo.sh using sh robomongo.sh in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I have Just downloaded the `robomongo` 64 bit for `ubuntu` from the Official site.
Then I opened my terminal and went through the folder structure and executed the command from `bin` folder.

```
sh robomongo.sh
```

I'm getting an error like this

```
robomongo.sh: 5: robomongo.sh: Bad substitution
```

Help me.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Solution : when i downloaded the tar file from official site, I just opened it using ubuntu software center. It got Installed and working fine now.

Answer (score 6):

```
To install MongoDB Administration: RoboMongo version (0.8.*) on Ubuntu
```

1. Download **64 bit .deb package** for Debian/Ubuntu
2. Open **.deb package** with **Ubuntu Software Center**
3. MongoDB Administration: RoboMongo has been installed on your linux machine

---

```
To install MongoDB Administration: RoboMongo version (0.9.*) on Ubuntu
```

1. Download .tar.gz file for ubuntu [ Source: [RoboMongo Website](https://robomongo.org/download), for example 0.9.0 RC8 1.e **robomongo-0.9.0-rc8-linux-x86_64-c113244.tar.gz** ]
2. **tar** **-xvzf** **robomongo-0.9.0-rc8-linux-x86_64-c113244.tar.gz** [ Assuming you have **robomongo-0.9.0-rc8-linux-x86_64-c113244.tar.gz** file into your Download directory ]
3. sudo **mv** **PATH_TO_RoboMongo_Tar_File** **/usr/local/lib/robomongo/**

> Example: sudo mv ~/Downloads/robomongo-0.9.0-rc8-linux-x86_64-c113244/
>   /usr/local/lib/robomongo/

4. cd /usr/local/lib/robomongo/bin
5. Right click on robomongo file i.e executable (application/x-executable)

   5.1. Now click on "Make Link" option
6. You may put this shortcut icon to desktop to launch RoboMongo GUI

Answer (score 0):

in Terminal you can use just this command **robomongo** and you can install stable version   robomongo with using **sudo apt-get install robomongo**

Comment: Firstly Thanks,getting this error E: Unable to locate package robomongo .

Comment: maybe currently install other application or doing update. done restart

Comment: No. I have tried the same command from another system the error I got the same.

Comment: I think this is not robomongo package problem. this your ubuntu system problem. maybe chack http://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-by-apt

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it.

Comment: Solution : when i downloaded the tar file from official site, I just opened it using ubuntu software center. It got Installed and working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Solution : when i downloaded the tar file from official site, I just opened it using ubuntu software center. It got Installed and working fine now.

Comment: @Anton right click on that file and open with ubuntu software center. upvoke the answer if it solves your problem !

Comment: Ubuntu Software Center complains that the file cannot be opened. Anyway, already installed that in the old-style way (that is, manually).

Comment: Firstly download the tar file from the [link](http://app.robomongo.org/download.html) and extract the file and go to bin folder you can see robomongo.sh just run it.

Answer (score 0):

answer of [@mistertandon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37184845/1908296) is nice But I will be more clear

There Two ways to install `robomongo` program into ubuntu using command line:

**First way**

1.1 download tar.gz file from [Official `robomongo` website](https://robomongo.org/download)(choose version you need to install and get it's tar.gz download file url)

```
wget https://download.robomongo.org/0.9.0/linux/robomongo-0.9.0-linux-x86_64-0786489.tar.gz
```

1.2 extract tar.gz file

```
 tar -xvzf robomongo-0.9.0-linux-x86_64-0786489.tar.gz
```

1.3 mv files and folders into the result folder from extraction operation
    into folder `robomongo` under `/usr/local/bin`

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/bin/robomongo
sudo mv  robomongo-0.9.0-linux-x86_64-0786489/* /usr/local/bin/robomongo
```

1.4 make sure excute file for `robomongo` program which exists under 
 `/usr/local/bin/robomongo/bin` folder is excutable file

```
cd /usr/local/bin/robomongo/bin
sudo chmod +x robomongo ## run command only if robomongo isn't excutable file
./robomongo
```

**Second way**

2.1 download deb file from [Official `robomongo` website](https://robomongo.org/download)(choose version you need to install and get it's deb download file url)

```
wget https://download.robomongo.org/0.8.5/linux/robomongo-0.8.5-x86_64.deb
```

2.2 install deb file using dpkg command line

```
sudo dpkg -i robomongo-0.8.5-x86_64.deb
```

2.3 open `robomongo` program using command line by run

```
robomongo
```

**Very Important Notice**:

all version less than `robomongo` program 0.9.* version has both `deb` file and `tar.gz` file download urls(I didn't know what is the reason for this) So If you need download version less than 0.9.* version you can use one of two ways But If you need download version 0.9.0 there only one way is the first ones

more links about install `robomongo` program: [link 1](http://trimc-db.blogspot.com.eg/2015/01/mongodb-administration-robomongo-on.html), [link 2](http://hackwithin.com/2014/05/13/setup-development-machine/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to run robo3T go to lib folder and delete libstdc++. There you will find two file with similiar name delete both and it will work.