# How to install Robomongo from tar.gz file as a program in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, robo3t

Nowadays robomongo developers releasing the new versions of robomongo as `tar.gz` not in `.deb` packages that was easy for double click installations. But that option is no longer available. So how to install it as a program in Ubuntu. I have tried extracting the package and install but failed.

```
admin@admin-lenovo:~$ cd Downloads/
admin@admin-lenovo:~/Downloads$ tar -xzf robomongo-0.9.0-rc4-linux-x86_64-8c830b6.tar.gz 
admin@admin-lenovo:~/Downloads$ cd robomongo-0.9.0-rc4-linux-x86_64-8c830b6/
admin@admin-lenovo:~/Downloads/robomongo-0.9.0-rc4-linux-x86_64-8c830b6$ ./configure
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

Also `.make` and `./install` failed as no files found. How to install it as a program?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**1. First Download the version from the official Robomongo website bellow:**

[Download Robomongo From Official website using this link](https://robomongo.org/download)

**2.Then extract the downloaded tar.gz file in your downloads folder.**

**3**. Copy and paste the extracted folder into your ***opt*** folder

```
/opt
```

NB: If you don't have permission to paste in this folder use the bellow command in terminal to access the folder.

```
$ sudo chmod -R 777 /opt
```

**4.** Open the opt/robomongo/bin folder and launch Robomongo by clicking the executable icon.

```
opt/robomongo/bin
```

**5. Simply Create a database and right click on the Robomongo icon and select the lock to launcher option. This will create a shortcut t launch the Robomongo application at any time you need.**

Comment: sweet, in addition you can right click it icon on the launcher and choose **add to dash**

Comment: This is by far the best and simplest answer.

Comment: I really don't think you should `chmod 777 /opt`

Comment: @MaximoDominguez oh right, is there any other better option?

Comment: `chmod 777` you can do, not something you should do.

Answer (score 65):

Robomongo is now Robo 3T. Following are the updated steps:

1. Download the tar file from [robomongo site](https://robomongo.org/download). The current file is `robo3t-1.1.1-linux-x86_64-c93c6b0.tar.gz`, but yours could be different.
2. Open up the terminal, switch to download directory and run the following commands:

   ```
   $ tar -xvzf robo3t-1.1.1-linux-x86_64-c93c6b0.tar.gz
   $ sudo mkdir /usr/local/bin/robomongo
   $ sudo mv  robo3t-1.1.1-linux-x86_64-c93c6b0/* /usr/local/bin/robomongo
   $ cd /usr/local/bin/robomongo/bin
   $ sudo chmod +x robo3t 
   $ sudo gedit ~/.bashrc
   ```
3. Add the following line to the end of `.bashrc` file:

   > alias robomongo='/usr/local/bin/robomongo/bin/robo3t'
4. Save and close the file. Now reload it using the following command:

   ```
   $ source ~/.bashrc
   ```
5. Then you can run robomongo from your terminal and it will work:

   ```
   $ robomongo
   ```

Comment: This is the correct answer, but there is a bug in the latest version and you will need to `rm lib/libstdc++*` to make it work

Comment: Great answer and pin-point comment. @CascadiaJS, please edit the answer with your valuable input. Answer and comment did solve my problem. Thanks!

Comment: location of ``libstdc++*`` is  actually ``/usr/local/bin/robomongo/lib`` so the delete command should look like:
``rm /usr/local/bin/robomongo/lib/libstdc++*``

Comment: If you don't have gedit check out this [page](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/gedit)! Or change the gedit command for vim.

Comment: Perfect Solution step by step . Thanks

Answer (score 35):

You can also put the robomongo into /usr/bin like I do:

```
tar xf robomongo-0.9.0-rc8-linux-x86_64-c113244.tar.gz

sudo mv robomongo-0.9.0-rc8-linux-x86_64-c113244/ /usr/bin/robomongo

export PATH=/usr/bin/robomongo/bin:$PATH
```

If you are using fish shell, you need to change the last line to:

```
set PATH $PATH /usr/bin/robomongo/bin
```

Now you can start it with command:

```
robomongo
```

Answer (score 16):

Pulled this from my dotfiles.  It's ugly but it works... and it's a bit more verbose so it should be understandable to most:

```
# Pull down and install Robomongo by copying files
cd /tmp
wget https://download.robomongo.org/0.9.0/linux/robomongo-0.9.0-linux-x86_64-0786489.tar.gz
tar xf robomongo-0.9.0-linux-x86_64-0786489.tar.gz
sudo mv ./robomongo-0.9.0-linux-x86_64-0786489 /opt/robomongo
cd /usr/sbin
sudo ln -s /opt/robomongo/bin/robomongo

# Grab image to use for icon
cd /opt/robomongo
wget http://mongodb-tools.com/img/robomongo.png

# Create desktop entry
touch /tmp/robomongo.txt
echo "[Desktop Entry]" >> /tmp/robomongo.txt
echo "Encoding=UTF-8" >> /tmp/robomongo.txt
echo "Name=Robomongo" >> /tmp/robomongo.txt
echo "Comment=Launch Robomongo" >> /tmp/robomongo.txt
echo "Icon=/opt/robomongo/robomongo.png" >> /tmp/robomongo.txt
echo "Exec=/usr/sbin/robomono" >> /tmp/robomongo.txt
echo "Terminal=false" >> /tmp/robomongo.txt
echo "Type=Application" >> /tmp/robomongo.txt
echo "Categories=Developer;" >> /tmp/robomongo.txt
echo "StartupNotify=true" >> /tmp/robomongo.txt
mv /tmp/robomongo.txt ~/.local/share/applications/robomongo.desktop
```

Comment: there is a typo:
echo "Exec=/usr/sbin/robomongo" >> /tmp/robomongo.txt

Answer (score 14):

You can first extract the package:

```
cd ~/Downloads
tar -xzf robo3t-x.x.x-linux-x86_64-xxxxxxx.tar.gz
```

You can rename the folder to something simpler

```
mv robo3t-x.x.x-linux-x86_64-xxxxxxx robo3t
```

Dowload any images with format .png [click here][1]
(For whatever reason, the Robo3T package itself does not contain any png file for the icon)

Save the image like robo3t.png and move this image to folder robo3t and then, instead of dumping the whole thing in `/usr` you can transfer this directory to `/opt` directory and symlink the binary file to `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`. This makes for a better way of organising your applications, and [keeping such add-on packages is what `/opt` is for](http://www.extradrm.com/?p=2266#:%7E:text=According%20to%20the%20Filesystem%20Hierarchy,use%20cases%20seem%20pretty%20similar.).

So first move the directory

```
sudo mv robo3t /opt
```

and then symlink it like so

```
sudo ln -s /opt/robo3t/bin/robo3t /usr/bin/robo3t
```

then you can create an Unity desktop file for your launcher

```
nano ~/.local/share/applications/robo3t.desktop
```

and finally; paste the next code in the file newly created

```
 [Desktop Entry]
       Encoding=UTF-8
       Name=Robo 3T
       Exec=robo3t
       Icon=/opt/robo3t/robo3t.png
       Terminal=false
       Type=Application
       Categories=Development;
```

And Happy coding!

Answer (score 10):

Currently there is no installer for **robomongo-0.9.0-rc4**. you can create a desktop shortcut to **robomongo-0.9.0-rc4-linux-x86_64-8c830b6/bin/robomongo** file and use it just like any other Ubuntu app. Take a look at this tutorial https://askubuntu.com/a/142197/71544

Comment: Step wise solution, already answered on stackoverflow [**To install MongoDB Administration: RoboMongo version 0.9.* on Ubuntu**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33233236/unable-to-run-robomongo-sh-using-sh-robomongo-sh-in-ubuntu-14-04/37184845#37184845)

Answer (score 8):

**Wathc this Video**
[How to install robomongo on ubuntu 16.4](https://youtu.be/0Fm64ZKGy4I)

**OR**
**Follow Below Steps**

**Open Terminal and run the below command**

```
wget https://download.robomongo.org/0.9.0/linux/robomongo-0.9.0-linux-x86_64-0786489.tar.gz
```

**Extract the tar.gz file to enter below command**

```
tar -xvzf robomongo-0.9.0-linux-x86_64-0786489.tar.gz
```

**create a dir /usr/local/bin dir name directory name robomongo and move it to extract file into robomongo directory**

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/bin/robomongo
sudo mv  robomongo-0.9.0-linux-x86_64-0786489/* /usr/local/bin/robomongo
```

**run command only if robomongo isn't executable file**

```
cd /usr/local/bin/robomongo/bin
sudo chmod +x robomongo 
./robomongo
```

Comment: thank you so much. this is the one which worked for me. i tried different methods and when i open robomongo collections are not showing and i cannot create any collections. this is the only one which solved my problem. thank you again

Comment: This is the only method that worked for me as well. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 3):

Don't worry about how to install Robo-3T on your Linux machine, follow these simple steps:

1. Download script from [Robo3T-Installation-With-Desktop Entry](https://gist.github.com/Chetan07j/ef98f17a699c1ff2ef7c34903c3c0389)
2. Open terminal in directory where above file is downloaded and run below command

   `sudo chmod +x ./Robo3T-Installation-Menu.sh`
3. Then type below command and hit enter

   `./Robo3T-Installation-Menu.sh`
4. Just wait to complete it, once completed enjoy RoboMongo. Search in menu with name "**Robo 3T**".

Comment: This script is for postman. I think this is the correct link you meant to post https://gist.github.com/Chetan07j/ef98f17a699c1ff2ef7c34903c3c0389. And yes, this script works!

Comment: @RaphaelOnofre thanks for pointing mistake, link updated now

Answer (score 2):

Well, I do not know if it might still help, but one efficient way to install Robomongo from `tar.gz` file is the following:

1. Go to https://robomongo.org/download to grab the `tar.gz` file,
2. After download,

   ```
   cd Downloads/*
   ```

   and then type in the terminal:

   ```
   $ sudo tar xzf robo3t-1.3.1-linux-x86_64-7419c406.tar.gz -C /opt/
   ```
3. Make sure your file has been unzipped in the `/opt` directory by checking:

   ```
   $ ls -lh /opt/
   ```
4. Next, install it by doing:

   ```
   $ sudo /opt/robo3t-1.3.1-linux-x86_64-7419c406/bin/robo3t
   ```
5. The installation wizard pops up and accept the terms and continue installation. Then Enjoy

> **NB:** You will not see the robot3t icon in the start menu. So to start robot3t, always
>   `/opt/robo3t-1.3.1-linux-x86_64-7419c406/bin/robo3t` to launch robo3T.

Hope it helps ;)