# Robo 3T error: Could not connect to any X display

Tags: mongodb, robo3t, fedora-27

I am trying to set up Robo 3T tool for MongoDB. I have followed the steps given in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45855674/5483561) to install robo3t on my machine running Fedora 27. But when I try to run the executable, I get the following error :

```
root@localhost: /usr/local/bin/robomongo/bin# ./robo3t 
QStandardPaths: wrong ownership on runtime directory /run/user/1000, 1000 instead of 0
No protocol specified
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0
Could not connect to any X display.
```

I am installing `robo3t 1.3.1`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `wrong ownership on runtime directory` - try starting as your user instead of root.

Comment: I am running it from root only. You can see that in the error snippet that I have added. Anyway, I later recalled that I can just run it by clicking on the executable in robo3t/bin/ folder. So, that worked.